# want to connect local DB2 database with IBM bluemix App

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Corporate AS400 server having Application and database DB2 running. currently there is no reporting tool for this application.

Planning to create new application on IBM bluemix with PHP. how can I connect secure DB2 database with IBM bluemix API.

Comment: You must have tagged your question with "secure gateway" for a reason...

Comment: Hi Abhishek29, weclome to stackoverflow.  In case you are wondering why your question has been down voted by other users, you may want to get aquainted with this link to make sure your questions meet the stackoverflow standards: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As commented by mustaccio, you have tagged your question with secure-gateway - have you seen the Bluemix secure gateway documentation?

> **About Secure Gateway**
>
> Last updated: 6 December 2016
>
> The Secure Gateway service provides you with a secure way to access
> your on-premises or cloud data from your Bluemix® application through
> a secure passage.
>
> **How Secure Gateway works**
>
> As displayed in the following diagram, the
> service works by using a client to connect to your Bluemix
> organization. Next, you add the service to your Bluemix organization.
> Then, by using the Secure Gateway UI or REST API you can begin
> creating your gateway by connecting to your client and creating a
> destination point to your on-premises or cloud data. To increase
> security, you can add application-side Transport Layer Security (TLS),
> which encrypts the data that travels from your app to the client. You
> can extend this security with client-side TLS, which encrypts the data
> from the client to the on-premises or cloud data. When you complete
> your gateway configuration, you can monitor the behavior of your
> gateways and destinations in the Secure Gateway Dashboard.
>
> [image]
>
> **Source:** https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_overview.html#sg_overview

The Secure Gateway documentation describes all the steps you need to follow to connect a Bluemix application to an internal service.